# How to load cmake script with more than one project with Qt Creator

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I have a CMake project, and until now, I was using Visual C++ for developing.

Using CMake-gui to generate a solution for VC++, it generates more than one project in the same solution. 
But when the script is loaded in qt-creator, only one project is defined, with all the code and folder tree inside, so I can not compile it (or I don't know how to do it).

How can I load the cmake file to load all the projects?

More info:

The first CMakeList.txt has some common configuration. Then, with 'add_subdirectory' function, I add a project to make a library, and another project to make a sample application to use this library.

Comment: Today 17MARCH2016, I opened root CMakeLists.txt, with similar "add_subdirectory" commands to other directories commands which are lead to mulitple targets....But I don't see this multiple targets as projects in QtCreator 3.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add multiple projects to the root cmake file with help of "add_subdirectory()". Then in Qt Creator you should open the root cmake file. After that you could choose which project to run in the select a kit for running (3) or debugging (4) application pane (check the [link](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-tour.html)).

It sad that you can't (or I don't know how) build only one project. You have to build all projects are added to the root cmake file and then choose which one of them you want to run.

I use Qt Creator 4.0 .

Comment: You can select the element you want to compile in the "Target" list (at least if you are using cmake as project definition). You can find this list into: "Projects->Build Steps->Details->Targets". Then, tick the element you want to build. By default 'all' option is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the offical doc http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-project-cmake.html 
My project have a similar structure, just open the top-most CMakeLists.txt file of the project, and qtcreator will import your project.

Comment: Today 17MARCH2016, I opened root CMakeLists.txt, with similar "add_subdirectory" commands to other directories commands which are lead to mulitple targets....But I don't see this multiple targets as projects in QtCreator 3.4.0 (

Comment: If those subdirectories contains more 'project' configuration scripts (CMake definitions 'project' command), QtCreator generates a list with those projects in the 'target element' selection menu (just over the Run button).

Comment: bruziuz, goe is right, if you add multiple projects to the root cmake file with help of "add_subdirectory()" then you could choose which project to run in the select a kit for running (3) or debugging (4) application pane (check the link). Link: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-tour.html