# How to configure CMakeLists.txt files of projects for have separated projects in Qt Creator instead one project

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I have 2 executable projects each of which depends from 2 libraries in one solution (root `CMakeLists.txt`). Build is ok and as result I have 2 libraries and 2 executable. But when I try to open root `CMakeLists.txt` in Qt creator instead 4 projects (`src1, src2, subproject1, subproject2`) & `CMakeLists.txt` in the root as result I have only 1 project with name `"Project"` which includes my 4 projects in `"Project"` container like this is include folders.

Also I cannot select project for run (`Set project "Project" as Active Project`) since this is only one project. After run from Qt the `MainProject1` was run.

StackOverflow and google propoused to use `add_subdirectory` for this but this does not work. In my `CMakeLists`'s for make depends and several projects I already had used `add_subdirectory`.

```
Qt version: 5.7.0.
Qt Creator version: 4.0.2.
Ubuntu
```

Please help me for fix this. Thanks in advance.

## Project structure & manual build & results: Succeed

#### Project structure:

```
root
    src1                    (executable which depends from subproject1 and subproject2)
        CMakeLists.txt
        main.cpp
    src2                    (executable which depends from subproject1 and subproject2)
        CMakeLists.txt
        main.cpp
    subproject1             (library)
        CMakeLists.txt
        hellow.cpp
        hellow.h
    subproject2             (library)
        CMakeLists.txt
        hellow.cpp
        hellow.h
    CMakeLists.txt          (the root CMakeLists)
```

#### Build & show results:

```
mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake .. && make &&
ll src1/MainProject1 && ll src2/MainProject2 && ll subproject1/libsubproject1.a && ll subproject2/libsubproject2.a
```

#### Results:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qqq qqq 13570 Jun  1 10:45 src1/MainProject1*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qqq qqq 13570 Jun  1 10:45 src2/MainProject2*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 qqq qqq 2820 Jun  1 10:45 subproject1/libsubproject1.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 qqq qqq 2828 Jun  1 10:45 subproject2/libsubproject2.a
```

All is ok

## CMakeLists.txt

#### Root CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_subdirectory( src1 )
add_subdirectory( src2 )
```

#### subproject1/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(subproject1)

set (sources
        ./hellow.cpp
        ./hellow.h
    )
add_library(subproject1 STATIC ${sources})
```

#### subproject2/CMakeLists.txt

Is the same but instead `subproject1`: `subproject2`

#### src1/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MainProject1)

set (sources
        ./main.cpp
    )

if (NOT TARGET subproject1)
     add_subdirectory( ./../subproject1 "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../subproject1" )
     add_subdirectory( ./../subproject2 "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../subproject2" )
endif() 

add_executable(MainProject1 ${sources})
target_link_libraries (MainProject1 subproject1)
target_link_libraries (MainProject1 subproject2)
add_dependencies( MainProject1 subproject1 )
add_dependencies( MainProject1 subproject2 )
```

#### src2/CMakeLists.txt

Is the same but instead `MainProject1`: `MainProject2`

## Open in Qt Creator: Failed

Open root CMakeLists.txt & configure for build in build folder.

#### Result of project structure (only 1 project):

```
root
    Project
        CMakeLists.txt
        src1
        src2
        subproject1
        subproject2
```

#### Expect (4 projects):

```
root
    src1
    src2
    subproject1
    subproject2
    CMakeLists.txt
```

#### Result of build:

```
cd build && ll src1/MainProject1 && ll src2/MainProject2 && ll subproject1/libsubproject1.a && ll subproject2/libsubproject2.a

-rwxrwxr-x 1 qqq qqq 38670 Jun  1 11:10 src1/MainProject1*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qqq qqq 38670 Jun  1 11:10 src2/MainProject2*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 qqq qqq 21900 Jun  1 11:10 subproject1/libsubproject1.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 qqq qqq 21908 Jun  1 11:10 subproject2/libsubproject2.a
```

Build is ok.

#### Run project

`MainProject1` was run. Cannot select project for run since Qt Creator perceives root `CMakeLists` as if it's only one project.

## Note

[Correspound link to question in forum.qt.io](http://forum.qt.io/topic/79851/how-to-configure-cmakelists-txt-files-of-projects-for-have-separated-projects-in-qt-creator-instead-one-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would structure your project the following way:

**Root CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MyComplexProject)
add_subdirectory( src1 )
add_subdirectory( src2 )
add_subdirectory( subproject1 )
add_subdirectory( subproject2 )
```

**src1/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set (sources
        ./main.cpp
    )

add_executable(MainProject1 ${sources})
target_link_libraries (MainProject1 subproject1 subproject2)
```

**subproject1/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set (sources
        ./hellow.cpp
        ./hellow.h
    )
add_library(subproject1 STATIC ${sources})
```

Please modify src2/CMakeLists.txt and subproject2/CMakeLists.txt equivalently.

Note: Only the top level CMakeLists.txt contains a project definition. The other CMakeLists contain only target definitions.

target_link_libraries add by default a dependency to the lib target. So it does not need to be done explicitely.

By adding dependencies with target_link_libraries to the executable targets CMake is able to figure out the correct build order.

edit:

See if [How to load cmake script with more than one project with Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466141/how-to-load-cmake-script-with-more-than-one-project-with-qt-creator) helps you further.

Comment: Thank you but this did not help. Result is the same. I only see that root project "Project" was renamed to "MyComplexProject". And about "Note: Only the top level CMakeLists.txt contains a project definition". This is not very good. I have to have a name for each project/library and be able to compile without root. E.g. open only subproject1 and compile it (if it does not have dependencies). Like in Visual Studio: if I open separetad lib in Visual Studio, not solution (.sln), it has name from .vcproj in any case and I able to compile it. Is it posible?

Comment: In other words CMakeLists's of subproject1 and subproject2 must be self-sufficient

Comment: Then please have a look into the link mentioned in the edit. The comments section of the accepted answer contains how to select the target to build in QtCreator.

Comment: A lot of thanks. This is not quite visually but really work. Correct way: "After that you could choose which project to run in the select a kit for running (3) or debugging (4) application pane ([link](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-tour.html))". So this is only one way and we cannot have separated projects in Qt Creator using cmake like in Visual Studio solutions. We can have only one root project from root CMakeLists.txt but we can select which executiable should be run for run or debug.

Comment: [Link to reply in Qt forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/79851/how-to-configure-cmakelists-txt-files-of-projects-for-have-separated-projects-in-qt-creator-instead-one-project/3)